# Can't make use of different proxies to perform subsequesnt requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, proxy

I've written a script in python using proxies to scrape the links of different posts traversing different pages from a webpage. `My goal here is to make two subsequesnt requests using different proxies from a list`.

***The script takes random proxies from the list and sends request by `make_requests()` function and then again makes another request by picking another proxy from the list using the newly populated links by `make_ano_requests()` function.***

Finally, `get_title()` function prints the result.

However, if any proxy doesn't work then it gets kicked out from the list by either of the two functions `make_requests()` or `make_ano_requests()`.

> When I run the script, it seems to be working but somewhere within it's execution, the script gets stuck and never acoomplish the task. How can I accomplish the task?

This is what I've written so far (***proxyVault*** contains fake proxies here):

```
import random
import requests
from random import choice
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'
lead_urls = [f'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort='
            f'newest&page={page}&pagesize=50' for page in range(1, 5)]

linkList = []

proxyVault = ['103.110.37.244:36022', '180.254.218.229:8080', '110.74.197.207:50632', '1.20.101.95:49001', '200.10.193.90:8080', '173.164.26.117:3128', '103.228.118.66:43002', '178.128.231.201:3128', '1.2.169.54:55312', '181.52.85.249:31487', '97.64.135.4:8080', '190.96.214.123:53251', '52.144.107.142:31923', '45.5.224.145:52035', '89.218.22.178:8080', '192.241.143.186:80', '113.53.29.218:38310', '36.78.131.182:39243']

def make_requests(url):
    proxy_url = choice(proxyVault)
    proxy = {'https': f'http://{proxy_url}'}
    try:
        res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
        linkList.extend([urljoin(base_url, item.get("href")) for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink")])
    except requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
        if proxy_url in proxyVault:
            proxyVault.remove(proxy_url)
            print(f'kicked out bad proxy by first func: {proxy_url}')
        return make_requests(url)

def make_ano_requests(url):
    proxy_url = choice(proxyVault)
    proxy = {'https': f'http://{proxy_url}'}
    try:
        res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy)
        get_title(res.text)
    except requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
        if proxy_url in proxyVault:
            proxyVault.remove(proxy_url)
            print(f'kicked out bad proxy by second func: {proxy_url}')
        return make_ano_requests(url)

def get_title(response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
    print(soup.select_one("h1[itemprop='name'] a").text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for lead_url in lead_urls:
        make_requests(lead_url)

    for single_link in linkList:
        make_ano_requests(single_link)
```

Comment: The code seems to work but is really slow with all the requests (even if proxies are removed). Added that you go through possibly really slow proxies will give the impression of freezing. Try printing different stages to see what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite possible that your `requests.get` are causing it to "hang", because they have no timeouts. Like the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) says:

> Nearly all production code should use this parameter in nearly all
>   requests. Failure to do so can cause your program to **hang
>   indefinitely**

So I suggest changing it to `res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy, timeout=1)` to prevent it from hanging.

It is however really sloooooow. To speed it up I would suggest removing the second request, and instead of getting the links from requests 1 getting the strings `[item.string for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink")]` which more often than not are the same as the titles.

**Edit, added code for catching timeouts in `request.get`:**

```
import random
import requests
from random import choice
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import urllib3

base_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'
lead_urls = [f'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort='
            f'newest&page={page}&pagesize=50' for page in range(1, 5)]

linkList = []

proxyVault = ['103.110.37.244:36022', '180.254.218.229:8080', '110.74.197.207:50632', '1.20.101.95:49001', '200.10.193.90:8080', '173.164.26.117:3128', '103.228.118.66:43002', '178.128.231.201:3128', '1.2.169.54:55312', '181.52.85.249:31487', '97.64.135.4:8080', '190.96.214.123:53251', '52.144.107.142:31923', '45.5.224.145:52035', '89.218.22.178:8080', '192.241.143.186:80', '113.53.29.218:38310', '36.78.131.182:39243']

def make_requests(url):
    proxy_url = choice(proxyVault)
    proxy = {'https': f'http://{proxy_url}'}
    try:
        res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy, timeout=1)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
        linkList.extend([urljoin(base_url, item.get("href")) for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink")])
    except (requests.exceptions.ProxyError,
            requests.exceptions.Timeout,
            requests.exceptions.ConnectionError,
            urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError):
        if proxy_url in proxyVault:
            proxyVault.remove(proxy_url)
            print(f'kicked out bad proxy by first func: {proxy_url}')
        return make_requests(url)

def make_ano_requests(url):
    proxy_url = choice(proxyVault)
    proxy = {'https': f'http://{proxy_url}'}
    try:
        res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy, timeout=1)
        get_title(res.text)
    except (requests.exceptions.ProxyError,
            requests.exceptions.Timeout,
            requests.exceptions.ConnectionError,
            urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError):
        if proxy_url in proxyVault:
            proxyVault.remove(proxy_url)
            print(f'kicked out bad proxy by second func: {proxy_url}')
        return make_ano_requests(url)

def get_title(response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
    print(soup.select_one("h1[itemprop='name'] a").text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for lead_url in lead_urls:
        make_requests(lead_url)

    for single_link in linkList:
        make_ano_requests(single_link)
```

Comment: Hi @SimonF, I tried to comply with your first suggestion but the thing is the script crashes within few seconds without producing any result. As for your second approach I already learned that from you in my eaarlier post. I just wanted to learn how to make subsequent requests using the way I tried above. Thanks.

Comment: So whats the cause of the crash? Traceback... If it gets a timeout you need to catch it the same way as proxyerror

Comment: @robots.txt I'm still waiting for the traceback... I'm pretty sure you're just not catching the new exception (timeout)

Comment: I would like to accept your answer and award the bounty if you provide me with a demo how the `timeout=1` should be set within `requests.get(url, proxies=proxy, timeout=1)` because evry time I try with that approach I get a `timeout exception` error almost instantly even if they are in `try/except` block. I only changed `res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy)` to `res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy,timeout=1)` in the two functions of my above script and ran that @SimonF.

Comment: @robots.txt Try the code above, I added all timeouterrors that I could think of can occur, as I don't have the traceback for you

Comment: Hi @SimonF, I thought to give you a little trouble by asking a question about a certain logic of the above script. Why should I use `return make_requests(url)` instead of only `make_requests(url)` within `make_requests()` function? Same goes for `make_ano_requests()`. Would be very grateful If I could get the clarity from you on this. Struggling to understand the logic. Thanks iin advance.

Comment: @robots.txt It’s considered good practice, in this case it is None either way as thats the default in python. However consider if you wanted to return the title and the links instead of using global variables and printing, then you would only need to add the return of said things, not the returns that are there already

Comment: Thanks for your response @SimonF. And If I'm not wrong then `return make_requests(url)` works more or less recursively when the script hits the exception, right?

Comment: @robots.txt Correct, it’s a recursive function

Comment: Hi @SimonF, would mind giving [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669696/how-can-i-make-my-script-go-on-with-any-existing-working-proxy-no-matter-how-man) a look in case there is any solution to offer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could speedup the proxy filter process by using asyncio and aiohttp. Something like this:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import random
import requests
from random import choice
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin


base_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'
lead_urls = [f'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort=' \
             f'newest&page={page}&pagesize=50' for page in range(1, 5)]
linkList = []

proxyVault = ['103.110.37.244:36022', '180.254.218.229:8080', '110.74.197.207:50632', '1.20.101.95:49001',
              '200.10.193.90:8080', '173.164.26.117:3128', '103.228.118.66:43002', '178.128.231.201:3128',
              '1.2.169.54:55312', '181.52.85.249:31487', '97.64.135.4:8080', '190.96.214.123:53251',
              '52.144.107.142:31923', '45.5.224.145:52035', '89.218.22.178:8080', '192.241.143.186:80',
              '113.53.29.218:38310', '36.78.131.182:39243']

def make_ano_requests(url):
    proxy_url = choice(proxyVault)
    proxy = {'https': f'http://{proxy_url}'}
    try:
        res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy, timeout=5)
        get_title(res.text)
    except requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
        if proxy_url in proxyVault:
            proxyVault.remove(proxy_url)
            print(f'kicked out bad proxy by second func: {proxy_url}')
        return make_ano_requests(url)


def get_title(response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
    print(soup.select_one("h1[itemprop='name'] a").text)


async def fetch(session, url, proxy_url):
    proxy = f'http://{proxy_url}'

    try:
        async with session.get(url, proxy=proxy) as response:
            return await response.text()
    except aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientProxyConnectionError:
        print(f'kicked out bad proxy by first func: {proxy_url}')
        proxyVault.remove(proxy_url)


async def make_requests():
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for proxy in proxyVault:
            tasks.append(fetch(session, base_url, proxy))

        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        print(f'Usefull proxies: {proxyVault}')
        for res in responses:
            if res:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
                linkList.extend(
                    [urljoin(base_url, item.get("href")) for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink")])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(make_requests())

    for single_link in linkList:
        make_ano_requests(single_link)
```